# Laplace of step and integration are same?

Tags: laplace-transform, proof

Why do we have Laplace transform of a step function and integrator is same.

\begin{align}
\mathcal L\left[u(t)\right] &= \frac 1s\\
\mathcal L  \left[  \int dt\right]  &= \frac 1s 
\end{align}

Please clear my doubt on this.

Comment: It might be more accurate to denote the second one as
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[\int f(t)\,dt\right] = \frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}\left[f(t)\right].
$$

Answer (score 4):

This is because the impulse response of an integrator is $h(t)=u(t)$. The output which is the convolution with the impulse respoponse is
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau$$
and with $h(t)=u(t)$ it becomes
$$\begin{align}
y(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{t}x(\tau)d\tau\tag{1}\end{align}$$
where $(1)$ is resulted from the fact that $$u(t-\tau)=\begin{cases}0& \forall \tau>t\\
1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ 
The transfer function (which is the Laplace transform of impulse response) is $$H(s)=\mathcal{L}\{h(t)=u(t)\}=\frac{1}{s}$$